# Controller call back function not working in Angular-Express-Bootstrap Seed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, ng-controller

I downloaded Angular-Express-Bootstrap seed from https://github.com/jimakker/angular-express-bootstrap-seed. I would like to perform routing through angular js which is performed perfectly. But now I am facing some problem on calling 'controller' in **controllers.js**.

I can call my MyCtrl1 by this way and working perfectly:

```
 function MyCtrl1() {
   alert('calling Myctrl1..')
 }
 MyCtrl1.$inject = [];
```

But whether I call like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'MyCtrl1';
      alert('calling'+ $scope.greeting+"..")
    }]);
```

The above controller call back function not working and shows this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] MyCtrl1 is not defined`

Routing Config in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters','myApp.controllers','myApp.services', 'myApp.directives','ngRoute'])
  app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) 
  {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            templateUrl: 'partial/1', 
            controller: MyCtrl1
        })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

I don't know why it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, I missed the quotes to the controller name in `$routeProvider`

Soln : `controller: 'MyCtrl1'`